# Override Django Model Manager

Tags: python, django, class, model, admin

This could should override the LogEntry model in order to use my custom manager instead of the default.

However when logging in to the admin site the activity log queryset it's not filtered.

```
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry
from django.db import models

class MyLogEntryManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(MyLogEntryManager, self).get_queryset().filter(content_type_id=1)

class MyLogEntry(LogEntry):
    objects = MyLogEntryManager()
```

Comment: This is my wild guess - not 100% sure - but since your custom class name is the same as the default `LogEntry` - the django contrib class is being considered instead of yours. Have you tried renaming your class name to something else and trying it ?

Comment: Thanks karthikr I've edited my question according to your suggestion but I'm still not getting the expected result.

Comment: also, make sure you have registered this class in the admin, and not django's

Comment: So should I unregister django's and then add mine?

Comment: Well, you dont have to since the names are different, but sure - just to be sure you can unreigster it